# jQuery form validator - at least one input filled

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a form.

```
<form id="form" action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="ajax()"> 
    <div class="element">
        <label for="first_name">Фамилия</label>
        <input type="text" id="first_name" class="text" name="first_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="second_name">Имя</label>
        <input type="text" id="second_name" class="text" name="second_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="last_name">Отчество</label>
        <input type="text" id="last_name" class="text" name="last_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="course">На каком вы курсе</label>
        <input type="text" id="course" class="text" name="course" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="math">Математика</label>
        <input type="text" id="math" class="text" name="math" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="programming">Программирование</label>
        <input type="text" id="programming" class="text" name="programming" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="english">Английский язык</label>
        <input type="text" id="english" class="text" name="english" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="history">История</label>
        <input type="text" id="history" class="text" name="history" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <input type="submit" id="send" class="send" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my validator

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //Валидация формы
    $(".send").validation(
        $("#first_name").validate({
            test: "blank", 
            invalid: function(){
                if($(this).nextAll(".error").notExists()) {
                    $(this).after('<div class="error">Введите корректное имя</div>');
                    $(this).nextAll(".error").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".name").next(".error").remove();
                    }, 2600);
                }
            },
            valid: function(){
                $(this).nextAll(".error").remove();
            }
        }),
        $("#second_name").validate({
            test: "blank email",
            invalid: function(){
                if($(this).nextAll(".error").notExists()) {
                    $(this).after('<div class="error">Введите корректный email</div>');
                    $(this).nextAll(".error").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".email").next(".error").remove();
                    }, 2600);
                }
            },
            valid: function(){
                $(this).nextAll(".error").remove();
            }
        }),
        $("#last_name").validate({
            test: "blank", 
            invalid: function(){
                if($(this).nextAll(".error").notExists()) {
                    $(this).after('<div class="error">Введите тему</div>');
                    $(this).nextAll(".error").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".subject").next(".error").remove();
                    }, 2600);
                }
            },
            valid: function(){
                $(this).nextAll(".error").remove();
            }
        }),
        $("#course").validate({
            test: "blank", 
            invalid: function(){
                if($(this).nextAll(".error").notExists()) {
                    $(this).after('<div class="error">Введите сообщение</div>');
                    $(this).nextAll(".error").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".message").next(".error").remove();
                    }, 2600);
                }
            },
            valid: function(){
                $(this).nextAll(".error").remove();
            }
        }),
        $("#math").validate({
            test: "blank", 
            invalid: function(){
                if($(this).nextAll(".error").notExists()) {
                    $(this).after('<div class="error">Введите сообщение</div>');
                    $(this).nextAll(".error").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".message").next(".error").remove();
                    }, 2600);
                }
            },
            valid: function(){
                $(this).nextAll(".error").remove();
            }
        }),
        $("#programming").validate({
            test: "blank", 
            invalid: function(){
                if($(this).nextAll(".error").notExists()) {
                    $(this).after('<div class="error">Введите сообщение</div>');
                    $(this).nextAll(".error").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".message").next(".error").remove();
                    }, 2600);
                }
            },
            valid: function(){
                $(this).nextAll(".error").remove();
            }
        }),
        $("#english").validate({
            test: "blank", 
            invalid: function(){
                if($(this).nextAll(".error").notExists()) {
                    $(this).after('<div class="error">Введите сообщение</div>');
                    $(this).nextAll(".error").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".message").next(".error").remove();
                    }, 2600);
                }
            },
            valid: function(){
                $(this).nextAll(".error").remove();
            }
        }),
        $("#history").validate({
            test: "blank", 
            invalid: function(){
                if($(this).nextAll(".error").notExists()) {
                    $(this).after('<div class="error">Введите сообщение</div>');
                    $(this).nextAll(".error").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".message").next(".error").remove();
                    }, 2600);
                }
            },
            valid: function(){
                $(this).nextAll(".error").remove();
            }
        })
    );
});
```

The fiels first_name, second_name, last_name, course are required. The others (math, programming, history, english) they are also required but only one of them, i mean if any of them is filled, it pass the validation. How can i do that?

Comment: Use [jquery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), and you can DRY that code up massively.

Comment: I'm already using jquery validate!

Comment: In that case apply your settings to the `form` element instead of each input individually.

Comment: Did you looked at my code? I already applied. I need to do a rule, that if one of 4 inputs are filled, pass the validation. how can i do it?

Comment: Of course I've looked at your code. You are attaching your validation rules incorrectly. Attach them to the `form` element instead, as per the examples in the documentation.

Comment: You mean this is incorrect? $("#first_name").validate({? How should it be then?

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".send").validation(  //  < -- what is this?
        $("#first_name").validate({
            test: "blank",         // <-- no such option
            invalid: function() {  // <-- no such option
                ....
            },
            valid: function() {    // <-- no such option
                ....
            }
        });
        $("#second_name").validate({
            ......
        });
    );
});
```

Your code is really broken.  You cannot just make up options for a plugin from thin air; they need to be defined by the developer of the plugin *before* you can use them.

1)  If you're using the jQuery Validation plugin, then why are all your calls to `.validate()` stuffed inside of something called `.validation()`?  What is `.validation()` supposed to be?  There is no such method defined for this plugin.

2)  There is no such jQuery Validate plugin option called `test`.  [See all options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate).

3)  There are no such jQuery Validate plugin callback functions called `valid` and `invalid`.  Use the `highlight`, `unhighlight`, `errorPlacement`, and `success` callback functions to control the placement and toggling of errors.

4)  You do not attach `.validate()` to every input element on the form.  It only gets attached to the `form` element and it only gets called once within the DOM ready event to initialize the plugin.

5)  You don't need any inline JavaScript when using jQuery, and `.ajax()` belongs inside of the `submitHandler` callback function of the plugin.

I suggest that you...

- read the [online documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org)
- follow the [examples provided](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)
- read [the SO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info)
- look at the code in various SO questions tagged with [jquery-validate](/questions/tagged/jquery-validate).

Otherwise, here is a very basic working example:

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            foo: {
                required: true
            },
            bar: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // ajax goes here
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO  http://jsfiddle.net/QKvB4/**

---

After you fix all that, include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js) and use the `require_from_group` method to make at least one field, from a group of fields, required.